# Makefile: $(eval $(call ...)) in recipe with variable expansion

Tags: shell, makefile, eval, call, expansion

I would like to understand how to correctly test the value of shell output. This is my piece of code:

```
DB := my_database
WORKING_SCHEMA := toto
export WORKING_SCHEMA

check_working_schema = $(shell echo "SELECT EXISTS ( \
                       SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace \
                       WHERE nspname = :'sel_schema'\
                       ); " | psql -d $(DB) -q -t -A --variable sel_schema=$$1)

$(info $(check_working_schema))

.PHONY: rule1
rule1 :
ifeq "$(eval $(call check_working_schema, $(WORKING_SCHEMA)))" "t" 
        $(info in true part)
else
        $(info in false par)
endif
```

The test does not pass, I do not know where is the error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of misconceptions here.  The most important thing to understand is that when make *evaluates* the `eval` function, the result of that evaluation is the empty string.  Eval is used to interpret make syntax... it's sort of like a make `include` statement except instead of a file, it "includes" a string.

So saying something like:

```
ifeq "$(eval ...)" "t"
```

can never work because the first clause will always be the empty string.

The next thing to realize is that, as above, `eval` expects to get makefile syntax.  But the results of the `call` function will be the output of the `psql` statement, which is definitely not makefile syntax.

I'm not sure why you're using `eval` here.  Why not just use:

```
ifeq "$(call check_working_schema, $(WORKING_SCHEMA))" "t"
```

?

Also, your `check_working_schema` function is not right because it's escaping the `$1` argument; you want that argument to be expanded; that's the whole point of using `call`.

And FWIW, I would use `$(strip ...)` here as well because make is sensitive to whitespace:

```
check_working_schema = $(strip $(shell echo "SELECT EXISTS ( \
                       SELECT 1 FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace \
                       WHERE nspname = :'sel_schema'\
                       ); " | psql -d $(DB) -q -t -A --variable sel_schema='$1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

after a lot of reading I finally found a solution.

I was confused because I want to escape the second variable passed to psql. The $(DB) value is the same during the whole Makefile but the schema name can vary.

So this is my solution:

```
DB = my_db
# first instanciation of working_schema
WORKING SCHEMA = toto

DB := $(strip $(DB))
WORKING_SCHEMA := $(strip $(WORKING_SCHEMA))

checking_working_schema =$$(shell echo -e "\\\timing of \n\
             SELECT EXISTS ( \
                   SELECT 1 \
                   FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace \
                   WHERE nspname = :'sel_schema' \
             );" \
             | psql -d $(DB) -q -t -A --variable sel_schema=$1)

$(eval working_schema_exist:=$(call checking_working_schema,$(WORKING_SCHEMA)))

ifeq "$(working_schema_exist)" "t"
  $(info in true part)
else
  $(info in false part)
endif
```

then later I modify the value of $(WORKING_SCHEMA).